# Is it possible to automate Silverlight with PowerShell?

Tags: silverlight, powershell, automation, automated-tests

It is possible to automate Silverlight with PowerShell?
I want to control Silverlight, press buttons etc.

Like automation with the IExplorer:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
$ie.Document.getElementById("ButtonID")|foreach{
       $_.Click()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching](http://www.google.nl/search?aq=0&oq=automated+testing+sil&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=automated+testing+silverlight) surfaces [white](http://white.codeplex.com/) it supports Silverlight [see the Silverlight wiki entry](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight&referringTitle=Home). Being a .NET library it should be straight forward to use it with PowerShell. [This](http://testing.stackexchange.com/questions/218/automated-testing-of-silverlight) [testing.stackexchange](http://testing.stackexchange.com/) [question](http://testing.stackexchange.com/questions/218/automated-testing-of-silverlight) might also be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a subset of the .NET framework. Certain DLLs will not work within a Silverlight App. If you want the presentation of Silverlight with all the functionality of .NET, then I would suggest using WPF instead.